# How do I cast array of unsigned short to an array of int?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, casting

I have 2 arrays:

```
unsigned short* array1;
int* array2;
```

Is there a quick way to get all the data in array1 into array2 such that the values of `array2[0]=array1[0], array2[1] = array1[1]` ...etc.

My question mentions casting but I think that's wishful thinking!
Obviously I can do this element by element using a for loop but I'm writing an image processing application and speed is key. If not casting then is there any other solution? Thanks.

Comment: You need to copy and convert (which happens automatically) each and every value (unless, in your implementation, `sizeof (short) == sizeof (int)`).

Comment: why are you using raw arrays, why are you not using `std::vector`. why are you using `unsigned`. why are you using `short`. that said, use `std::copy` to copy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (sizeof (int) == sizeof (short)) {
    array2 = (int*)array1; // UB: this may not work on some implementations
} else {
    // allocate memory for array2
    for (i = 0; i < nelems; i++) {
        array2[i] = array1[i];
    }
    // possibly release resources for array1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I cast array of unsigned short to an array of int?

You don't. If you do, and you use the result, you'll have some nice undefined behavior at hand.

> Is there a quick way to get all the data in array1 into array2

Yes, copy the array elements. It will be fast on any decent modern computer.